# conditional probabilities on exchangeable random variables

Tags: probability-theory

If $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n$ is a finitely exchangeable sequence of random variables, then why is $P(X_n | X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1})=P(X_n)$?

I've tried using symmetry but I can't split $P(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ into a product of $P(X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1})$ times $P(X_n)$.  Also I've thought this may use DeFinetti's theorem.

Is this merely a case of DeFinetti's by saying that $\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1})$ is an exchangeable sigma algebra, and so conditional on this sigma algebra, the $X_i$'s are iid?

Because then I'm unsure if that's an exchangeable sigma algebra since we only know $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n$ is exchangeable, not $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{n-1}$...

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong. An exchangeable sequence of length $n$ worth keeping in mind is when each $X_k$ is sampled from a set $S$ of size $n$, uniformly and without replacement. Then the distribution of every $X_k$ is uniform on $S$ but the conditional distribution of $X_n$ conditionally on $(X_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n-1}$ is the Dirac mass at the only point in $S\setminus\{X_k\mid1\leqslant k\leqslant n-1\}$.

(Re the last paragraph in the question: it is a general fact that if $(X_t)_{t\in S}$ is exchangeable and if $T\subset S$, then $(X_t)_{t\in T}$ is exchangeable as well.)

Comment: Thanks!  Also why does it follow that the $X_i$ are identically distributed from exchangeability.

Comment: Use a permutation exchangeing the indices of the two random variables you are interested in.

Comment: But that only shows P(X1,X2)=P(X2,X1).  That's where I was stuck earlier because the conditional probabilities P(X1|X2) and P(X2|X1) must be equal.

Comment: If (X,Y) and (Y,X) have the same distribution, then X and Y have the same distribution.

Comment: Oh, is this because $P(X\in A) = P(X\in A, Y\in \mathbb{R}) = P(Y\in A, X\in \mathbb{R}) = P(Y\in A)$?

Cool, I never realized $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ having the same joint distributions implied $X$ and $Y$ had the same distribution!

Comment: More generally, if random vectors share the same distribution then u(X) and u(Y) have the same distribution as well, for every function u. The present case is when u is the projection on the first coordinate.